# Failed type inference in local function

Tags: typescript

I'm stuck in a type inference that fails but it's not clear to me why. Here's the code:

```
type A = {
    kind: 'A',
    aaa : string,
}

type B = {
    kind: 'B',
}

type C =
        | A
        | B;

export function test(items: Array<C>) {
    for (let item of items) {
        switch (item.kind) {
        case 'A':
            console.log(item.aaa); // this compiles correctly
            let f = () => {
                console.log(item.aaa); // this gives error:
                // error TS2339: Property 'aaa' does not exist on type 'C'.
                // Property 'aaa' does not exist on type 'B'.
            };
            f();
        }
    }
}
```

In the switch statement I differentiate between the or types in first case, I manage type A;
compiler seems to understand what I'm doing, since console.log compiles correctly just after the case; then, defining a function, same console.log does not compile, giving an error that leads
me to think that compiler is not using the inferred type (A) inside the context of the function f...
but I do not understand why, since function is defined in the scope where type is already known to be A. Any clue?

My package.json file gives me following versions of things:

```
    ...
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "ts-patch": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The control-flow analysis of TypeScript doesn't go that deep and the type inference for `item` is limited to the scope of the `switch` statement.

One possible way to get around this and to keep the narrowed type by passing `item` to `f` by an explicitly typed parameter.

```
type A = {
  kind: "A";
  aaa: string;
};

type B = {
  kind: "B";
};

type C = A | B;

export function test(items: Array<C>) {
  for (let item of items) {
    switch (item.kind) {
      case "A":
        console.log(item.aaa);
        let f = (itemA: A) => {
          console.log(itemA.aaa);
        };
        f(item);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah got a similar idea, I just added that first line to f body and things compile: `let itemA : A = item as A; console.log(itemA.aaa);`

Answer (score 1):

That's due to the trade-offs made in the control flow analysis.

It's in this famous issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998